# How to get the parent entity from the child primary key in spring data jpa?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Hi I have parent entity User which has one to many relation with Vehicle entity and vehicle entity has many to one relation with User. I have a foreign key "user_fk" in my vehicle table. I have a UserRepository which extends Spring Data JPARepository that has save and findById methods.

Also I have two attributes in vehicle table which uniquely identifies a vehicle and I need to use that data to find out the corresponding User Object .I know it can be simply done by creating a Vehicle Repository which extends JPA repository and can use the find by method but I don't want to create a new Vehicle repository class just to achieve this functionality. How can I find the User_fk column value or User object without creating Vehicle Repository??Can I achieve this using UserRepository??

My UserClass:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "usr")
    class User{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userId;
    private String username;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Vehicle> vehicles= new ArrayList<>();
    //getters and setters
    }
```

My vehicleClass:

```
       @Entity
       @Table(name = "vehicle")
       class Vehicle{
       @Id
       @Column(name = "vehicle_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       private Long vehicleId;
       private String vehicleName;
       @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       @JoinColumn(name = "user_fk" , nullable = false)
       private User user;
      //getters and setters 
      }
```

I have the values of vehicleId and vehicleName and from these two attribute values I want to get the User object.

I don't want to create a vehicle repository only just to find the User object.I know it can be achieved by creating a Vehicle Repository which extends JPA repository in springdatajpa.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it from your user repository like this

```
User findByVehicles_VehicleIdAndVehicles_VehicleName(Long id, String name);
```

note that this will throw an exception if there's multiple users satisfying the conditions

If you want to get the id only you have to rely on custom query

```
@Query("select u.userId from User u join u.vehicles v where v.vehicleId=?1 and v.vehicleName=?2")
Long getUserIdByVehicleIdAndName(Long id, Long name);
```

Comment: I just need the corresponding value of column user_fk

Comment: Thank you .I will just try this.

Comment: I need to use this in my userRepository class.Right??

Comment: Yes, use it in your user repository

Comment: Just a small thing what if my attribute name and column name different.Suppose my attribute name is vehcile id and column name is vehicle_identifier. which one should we use in the query or in the findbymethod??

Comment: Here we use the JPA query language means use the properties of your class, you can use native language and use table fields.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a JPQL query with a JOIN  in the UserRepository:

```
@Query("select u from User u JOIN u.vehicles v where v.vehicleId = :vehicleId and v.vehicleName= :vehicleName")
User findUserByVehicleIdAndName(@Param("vehicleId") Long vehicleId, @Param("vehicleName") String vehicleName);
```